# getting Error in wordpress,when i am trying to open my website in web .it will display error

Tags: wordpress

Warning: require_once(/home/keganquimby/svtalentspace.com/wp-head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/keganquimby/svtalentspace.com/wp-config.php on line 99

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/keganquimby/svtalentspace.com/wp-head.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/keganquimby/svtalentspace.com/wp-config.php on line 99

Comment: please tell me.solution for this error

Comment: wp-head.php doesn't exist